# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'repopost.posts[0]') in expo simulator when i use axios in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

this is my axios. code:

```js
  const [repopost, setRepopost] = useState([]);
  const AuthStr = "Bearer ".concat(USER_TOKEN);
  const getRepopost = () => {
    axios
      .get("******", {
        headers: { Authorization: AuthStr },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        // If request is good...
        setRepopost(response.data);
        //  console.log(response.status);
        console.log(response.data);
        console.log(response.status);
        console.log(response.data.posts[0].media[0].media_url);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error " + error);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => getRepopost(), []);
```

and I get 200 ok status and I can see `media_url` in `console log`.
this is my return code:

```js
          <Image
              style={{
                height: 110,
                width: "100%",
                backgroundColor: "#252422",
                borderRadius: 5,
              }}
              source={{uri:repopost.posts[0].media[0].media_url}}
            />
```

but when i want get it in return first I get this error (undefined is not an object (evaluating `repopost.posts[0]`)) and when I comment image source and uncomment it, it will be ok.
I dont know what is my problem

Comment: sorry for writing my code like here